# Hide QLineEdit blinking cursor

Tags: qt, hide, caret, qlineedit

I am working on QT v5.2

I need to hide the blinking cursor (caret) of `QLineEdit` permanently.
But at the same time, I want the `QLineEdit` to be editable (so readOnly and/or setting editable false is not an option for me).

I am already changing the Background color of the `QLineEdit` when it is in focus, so I will know which `QLineEdit` widget is getting edited.
For my requirement, cursor (the blinking text cursor) display should not be there.

I have tried `styleSheets`, but I can't get the cursor hidden `( {color:transparent; text-shadow:0px 0px 0px black;} )`

Can someone please let me know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no standard way to do that, but you can use `setReadOnly` method which hides the cursor. When you call this method it disables processing of keys so you'll need to force it.
Inherit from QLineEdit and reimplement `keyPressEvent`.

```
LineEdit::LineEdit(QWidget* parent)
 : QLineEdit(parent)
{
  setReadOnly(true);      
}

void LineEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* e)
{
  setReadOnly(false);
  __super::keyPressEvent(e);
  setReadOnly(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you can create a single line `QTextEdit` and set the width of the cursor to zero by `setCursorWidth`.

For a single line `QTextEdit` you should subclass `QTextEdit` and do the following:

1. Disable word wrap.
2. Disable the scroll bars (AlwaysOff).
3. `setTabChangesFocus(true)`.
4. Set the sizePolicy to (`QSizePolicy::Expanding`, `QSizePolicy::Fixed`)
5. Reimplement `keyPressEvent()` to ignore the event when Enter/Return is hit
6. Reimplement `sizeHint` to return size depending on the font.

The implementation is :

```
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QStyleOption>
#include <QApplication>


class TextEdit : public QTextEdit
{
public:
        TextEdit()
        {
                setTabChangesFocus(true);
                setWordWrapMode(QTextOption::NoWrap);
                setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
                setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
                setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
                setFixedHeight(sizeHint().height());
        }
        void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
        {
                if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Return || event->key() == Qt::Key_Enter)
                        event->ignore();
                else
                        QTextEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
        }
        QSize sizeHint() const
        {
                QFontMetrics fm(font());
                int h = qMax(fm.height(), 14) + 4;
                int w = fm.width(QLatin1Char('x')) * 17 + 4;
                QStyleOptionFrameV2 opt;
                opt.initFrom(this);
                return (style()->sizeFromContents(QStyle::CT_LineEdit, &opt, QSize(w, h).
                        expandedTo(QApplication::globalStrut()), this));
        }
};
```

Now you can create an instance of `TextEdit` and set the cursor width to zero :

```
textEdit->setCursorWidth(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't get complicated:
In QtDesigner ,
1.Go the the lineEdit 's property tab
2.Change **focusPolicy** to **ClickFocus**

That's it...

Answer (score 1):

Most straight forward thing I found was stolen from this github repo:
https://github.com/igogo/qt5noblink/blob/master/qt5noblink.cpp

Basically you just want to disable the internal "blink timer" Qt thinks is somehow good UX (hint blinking cursors never were good UX and never will be - maybe try color or highlighting there eh design peeps).

So the code is pretty simple:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtGui


app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
app.setCursorFlashTime(0)
```

voilà.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in python:

```
# somelibraries

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.setFocus() # this is what you need!!!

        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Set the central widget of the Window.
        self.setCentralWidget(container)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem but `setReadOnly` is not a viable option because it alters the UI behavior in other places too.

Somewhere in a Qt-forum I found the following solution that actually solves the problem exactly where it occurs without having impact on other parts.

In the first step you need to derive from [QProxyStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qproxystyle.html#details) and overwrite the `pixelMetric` member function:

```
class CustomLineEditProxyStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    virtual int pixelMetric(PixelMetric metric, const QStyleOption* option = 0, const QWidget* widget = 0) const
    {
        if (metric == QStyle::PM_TextCursorWidth) 
            return 0;

        return QProxyStyle::pixelMetric(metric, option, widget);
    }
};
```

The custom function simply handles `QStyle::PM_TextCursorWidth` and forwards otherwise.

In your custom `LineEdit` class constructor you can then use the new Style like this:

```
m_pCustomLineEditStyle = new CustomLineEditProxyStyle();
setStyle(m_pCustomLineEditStyle);
```

And don't forget to delete it in the destructor since the ownership of the style is not transferred (see documentation). You can, of course, hand the style form outside to your `LineEdit` instance if you wish.